# Am I doing this epsilon-delta algebra correctly?

Tags: calculus

I've done a handful of really basic epsilon/delta algebraic evaluations, but I'm not sure if my answer to this one is correct. Is it okay for delta to be a function rather than a constant? Are my steps valid?

Given $f(x) = \sqrt x, L = \frac{1}{2}, c = \frac{1}{4}, \epsilon = 0.1$,

What is a $\delta | 0 < |x-c| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$ ?

$| \sqrt x - \frac{1}{2} | < 0.1$

$| \frac{(x - \frac{1}{4})}{\sqrt x + \frac{1}{2}} | < 0.1$

$|\frac{1}{\sqrt x + \frac{1}{2}}| \cdot |x - \frac{1}{4}| < 0.1$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt x + \frac{1}{2}} \cdot |x - \frac{1}{4}| < 0.1$

$|x - \frac{1}{4}| < 0.1 \cdot (\sqrt x + \frac{1}{2})$

$|x - \frac{1}{4}| < 0.1 \cdot (\frac{1 + 2 \sqrt x}{2})$

$|x - \frac{1}{4}| < \frac{1 + 2 \sqrt x}{20}$

Let $\delta = \frac{1 + 2 \sqrt x}{20}$.

$0 < |x - c| < \delta \implies |f(x) - L| < \epsilon$

Comment: $\delta$ should not depend on $x$.

Comment: Ask yourself this: how close does $x$ have to be to $\frac{1}{4}$ to be confident $\sqrt{x}$ will be within $0.1$ of $\frac{1}{2}$. Obviously, $0$ works, but that's not allowed. Try a few "test values" for $\delta$, like $1, 0.1$ and $0.01$. Maybe $\sqrt{0.1}$ will work, maybe we need to divide it by something to be sure our $x$ is "tight enough". You're not being asked to find the BEST possible delta, just one that will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $\frac{1}{2}-.1<\sqrt{x}<\frac{1}{2}+.1\iff.4<\sqrt{x}<.6\iff.16<x<.36$,

so we can take $\delta=\min\{\frac{1}{4}-.16,.36-\frac{1}{4}\}=\min\{.09, .11\}=.09$,

since $\displaystyle 0<\left|x-\frac{1}{4}\right|<.09\implies.16<x<.36\implies.4<\sqrt{x}<.6\implies\left|\sqrt{x}-\frac{1}{2}\right|<.1$

---

More generally, a similar argument shows that we can take $\delta=\epsilon-\epsilon^2$ if $0<\epsilon<\frac{1}{2}$,

and we can take $\delta=\frac{1}{4}$ if $\epsilon\ge\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thank you for explaining this! I think I have a better understanding--One of my mistakes was assuming that I should find a general solution for ANY epsilon, i.e. find $\delta(\epsilon)$. Rather, by applying a specific epsilon value, it becomes much easier to find $\delta(\epsilon=0.1)$, nevermind what, if anything, $\delta(\epsilon)$ might be.

Comment: You're welcome.  (I have edited my answer to cover the more general case, and I used the graph of $y=\sqrt{x}$ to get these ideas.)

Comment: Would it be clearer to say $\delta(\epsilon) = | \min(\epsilon^2 - \epsilon, \epsilon, \epsilon^2 + \epsilon)| = |\epsilon^2 - \epsilon|$, so $\delta(\epsilon = 0.1) = |0.1^2 - 0.1| = |-0.09| = 0.19$?

Comment: I would write it this way: $\delta(\epsilon)=\min(\epsilon-\epsilon^2, \epsilon+\epsilon^2)=\epsilon-\epsilon^2$, so $\delta(0.1)=.1-.1^2=.09$